# Multiple MediaPlayer background instead of 1

Tags: android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to run an App that has only one background song that runs on all activities. But some how when I open another activity, (all the activities are extends of the main activity), the application opens another session of the song. I tried to fix it but with no success.

I don't understand why the "Music:IsPlaying" is always false despite that the song is playing, this is my code:

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Music = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ad_matai);

        if (!Music.isPlaying())
        {
            Music.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void OpenMyProfile(View view)
    {
        Intent open_my_profile = new Intent(this,MyProfile.class);
        startActivity(open_my_profile);
    }

    public void OpenPeople(View view)
    {
        Intent open_people = new Intent(this,PazamPeople.class);
        startActivity(open_pazam_people);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't You use service for that? If You have task which should be active for longer than single activity lifecycle it should be service for that. Hit Google with 'music service android'

Comment: I don't want the music to play when i exit the app- that's why define it as a service is not good for me. I still want a single song to go above the activity lifecycle and play all the time. If anyone have a perfect solution it will be nice.

Comment: check out this links: http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/ , http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/services-tutorials-part-2-a-foreground-service.html